# SSH fails after changing Amazon EC2 instance region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When I created the EC2 instance, the default region was us-west. Then when the instance is running, I changed it to us-east, and the public DNS was also changed.

However, I SSH using the new DNS in putty, and it displays server refuses the key. If I switch back to us-west region, it shows the original DNS. Does anyone know why I cannot connect EC2 using us-east?

Comment: I'm curious as to how you are accomplishing changing regions in EC2. AFAIK there is not such feature. You can only copy AMIs across regions.

Comment: @Rico:I click the region selector in the top right.. Does that change the region?

Comment: yes, but regions have completely separate resources in AWS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the only way this could have happened is that if you created a similar instance in a new region. In which case your `keypairs` are different. You need to use the specific `keypair` for the region that you created it for.

Comment: I changed the region and saw the "Key Name" in the instance console is still the same key name.

Comment: @Sean the key may have the same name but they are different keys. Their content is different.

Comment: How can I get the current key after I changed the region? Thanks!

Comment: @Sean you can't, you just have to create new key pairs for each region.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I created a new key with the same name as original one, it still does not work.  I cannot bind the new key name to the instance. it looks I cannot change region after I created the instance?

Comment: @Sean no you can't change the region after you have created the instance. You can only change the size (when it's not running).

Comment: Regions are completely isolated to avoid data leakage. The IDs of everything (instances, AMIs, VPC... and Key-pairs) are different and each API call is directed to a specific region with its own IDs (and key-pairs).

Comment: Use the keypair from the region you originally created the instance in. The key is probably still embedded in the instances's /ssh/authorized keys. This fact will not be obvious from the AWS Console's details about your new or moved instance.